# groovy date: build list of all Fridays in 2011

Tags: groovy

How would one build a list of all Fridays in 2011, and allow for different date output, e.g. mm/dd/yyyy and yyyymmdd?

Comment: The naive solution seems straight-forward; start on 1/1, scan forward until a Friday, then `date.plus(7)` until you're no longer in the same year. Formatting is handled by the normal [format](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
use (groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def d = Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "01/01/2011")
    while (d[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] != Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        d = d + 1.day
    }
    while (d[Calendar.YEAR] == 2011) {
        println d.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
        d = d + 1.week
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I looked up the "use" syntax above, but I got too many hits! :-)  Can you explain what it does, or provide me a reference of it.

Comment: It applies the methods in a [Category](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Categories) class to other classes.  In this case, TimeCategory adds the methods `getDay()` and `getWeek()` to integer, so you can use the extremely readable notation `1.day` and `1.week` to refer to time durations.

Comment: Too cool.   Can I read about this general mechanism more?  I.e. where in groovy docs?

Comment: Check out [Groovy Goodness: Use Categories to Add Functionality to Classes](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-use-categories-to-add.html).

Comment: Thanks, wonderful.  I see what you are saying now about Category -- I thought it was specific to this example, but it really is general.  Thanks again @ataylor

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to ataylor's correct answer, you could do:

```
import static java.util.Calendar.*

def s = Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "01/01/2011")
def e = Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "12/31/2011")

(s..e).findAll {
  it[ DAY_OF_WEEK ] == FRIDAY
}.each {
  println it.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this is great too.

Comment: Tim, how'd you know (s..e) would build a range of dates?  (I'm still a "newbie"! :-)

Comment: I mean I know (1..5) or two integers, etc builds a range, but how does one know what things one can build ranges on?

Comment: @Ray Any class can be in a range as long as it implements [`next()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#next%28%29), [`previous()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#previous%28%29) and the `java.util.Comparable` interface (which [Date does](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)) :-)

Comment: Ah wonderful, thank you.   Both your answer and Ataylors are very helpful/informative.  I wrote Stackoverflow because I hate these situations where you can only select on answer.  Thanks for helping me understand this range stuff better.  Have a great day/evening.

Answer (score 0):

Both ataylor's answer and Tim's answer are correct and very informative -- see comments if you're coming up to speed on Groovy.

I hate these situations where I'm supposed to pick one as the answer over the other.  They are both right answers.  Stackoverflow won't change their stuff so I can select both as correct, so I will merely point to both as being correct.

Comment: I'd accept ataylor's answer.  He was first, and his does less work, as it locates the first Friday, then increments by 7 days to get each successive one (so at most will do 58 steps).  Mine will step through every day in the year, removing those that aren't Friday.